# Private var aiming at globar var does not change when the global changes

Tags: javascript, closures, global

I am trying to break my code into modules, and I have problems referencing the other modules of my app.

```
MYAPP = (function(my_app)
{

    var funcs = my_app.funcs;

    var module2 =
    {
         stupid_function = function ()
         {
            var some_var = "auwesome!";

            //let's call something from the other module...
            funcs.do_whatever();
         };

    };

    my_app.module2 = module2;

    return my_app;

})(MYAPP);
```

The problem comes when MYAPP.funcs changes. For example, when I initialize it and add new methods... since "funcs" was created inside of the closure, it has a copy of MYAPP.funcs and does not have the new stuff I need.

This is the way "funcs" gets more methods... when I execute the method MYAPP.funcs.init() the MYAPP.funcs is re-written by itself.

```
var MYAPP = (function (my_app, $)
{

    'use_strict';

     my_app.funcs = {};

         my_app.funcs.init = function ()
         {
            panel = my_app.dom.panel;
            funcs = my_app.funcs;
                query_fns = funcs.query;

                 my_app.funcs =
                 {
                       some_method: function () { ... },
                       do_whatever: function () { ... }
                 };

          };


    return my_app;

}(APP, jQuery));
```

Thanks in advance!!

---

In case it is interesting for anybody...

The method I am using for moduling is the "tight augmentation" http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=es-419&q=cache%3Aadequatelygood.com%2F2010%2F3%2FJavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth&btnG=

Comment: If `MYAPP.funcs` is an object, then where it was created doesn't make a difference. You don't have a "copy" of it, you references to it, so whenever you add new functions, the will be visible from all references.. I don't see in your code where you're updating `funcs`, but I do see that you're creating an implicit global variable `module2` before assigning it to `my_app`. Not sure why you'd use a global there.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just fixed the implied var mistake.

MYAPP.funcs is an object. In my code there is no example of how I augment the MYAPP.funcs. I need to have the DOM loaded to completely define the module, so what I do is create a MYAPP.funcs.init method that re-writes the MYAPP.funcs when I call it. I better enhance my examples, one sec...

Thanks

Comment: If you're saying that you're *replacing* `MYAPP.funcs` altogether with a new object, then yes, you'll lose the old data. You should probably be *updating* the object instead of replacing it.

Comment: That is the way I have been using for updating... now I see that rewriting the object is not the best way.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with modules or global... the difference is if you are changing object variable points to or what variable is pointing to:

```
var first = {my:"test"};
var second = first; // second points to object {my:"test"}
first.foo = 42; // updating the object, second points to it and can see the change
first = {my:"other"}; // new object, second still points to old  {my:"test", foo:42}
```

Comment: Looks like that, because I have the method MYAPP.funcs.init overwrite itself and redefine a new object without the init method.

Im gonna check but looks exactly like that!! thanks!